# How do I run specific queries in SCCM using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm, query

Could you advise how could I run query ID using command prompt? For example, I do not want to go to Monitoring-Queries-expand tree and search for the specific querry. I Just want to have script file, when I launch it the command show the result of my query or export it to csv file.
What is the syntaxis if I should go to File - connect via Windows Poweshell?

MS SCCM 2012 console version 5 site version 5

Comment: Your question's 'Title' should contain the question.  The info in your title should be in the body.  I think you are asking "How do I monitor queries in SCCM using Powershell?"

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to use PowerShell to run a CM Query? Then you can use built-in cmdlet:

```
Invoke-CMQuery -Name 'YourQueryName'
```

To get the detailed syntax of ***Invoke-CMQuery*** command, you can run below:

```
Get-Help Invoke-CMQuery
```

The output is different with running from GUI, however, you may still be able to use PowerShell to change the output style.